# Why is my 10 year old Meyer lemon tree suddenly producing orange fruit after producing yellow fruit for several years?

Tags: fruit-trees, lemons

My 10 year old Meyer lemon tree potted in 10 inch pot and doing well, started producing orange fruit instead of yellow fruit. I have pictures to demonstrate but I can't figure out how to attach them.

Comment: Welcome! Pictures can be tricky here. Here's the basic process. Press the gray "edit" word under your question. That will open it up. Press the icon that looks like a mountain, right after the brackets. A window will open that will ask if you want to add a picture from your computer or from a website. If the picture is on your computer, drag, drop or double-click it right there. If your photo is on the web, like a google album, post the web address. Then hit "add picture" and it should pop right in. If it doesn't work, leave a comment and we'll try something else! Don't give up!

Answer (score 1):

Has this tree produced yellow fruit in the past? If not, it may have been mislabeled when purchased. There are two other possibilities:

1. The [rootstock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rootstock) may have overgrown the [scion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grafting).
2. The fruit deepens in color as it becomes more mature.

Was previous fruit picked at a less mature stage?